# How to set up Tomcat7 web.xml file?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I have made a web service with eclipse which is deployed it as a .war file to Tomcat and can be seen in the localhost/manager page. However, when you try access the web service it returns a 404 error.
From other answers I have seen for this issue, it is apparently likely that my web.xml file is screwed up!

Could anyone help me or tell me how to set up the web.xml file correctly to point to my web service? It would be greatly appreciated. It should be noted that I have not added anything to my web.xml file because I am very new to Tomcat and am still not 100% sure how it works.

Many thanks in advance!

Edit: this is what my web.xml file currently looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>PasswordResetWS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please share your web.XML, which can be found under web-inf folder of your project

Comment: @PraveenRawat Just edited my post with my web.xml content

Comment: The web.xml looks fine, are you sure it's web.xml that is causing the problem?

Comment: @BillF Tbh, no i'm not really sure. It's just the conclusion I came to when reading how other people solved this problem.. Do you have any idea, by any chance, what other things might cause this to occur?

Comment: @RachelSolomon does your tomcat boots up okay? what are you using to build your war? maven? gradle? ant? are you using the proper ports to access your webserver? tomcat's default is 8080

Comment: @BillF Yeah, when I start up Tomcat it works fine. I have access to the homepage and to the manager page. It's only when I click on the application and try to access it from either its URL or from clicking it in the manager page that it gives the 404 error. I exported my Eclipse web service as a war file, so afaik i didnt use any of those.. And yeah, accessing it from the default port. Really not sure how I can fix this ..

Comment: @BillF also wanted to add that I checked the logs, and it doesnt give me any errors or information regarding this..

Comment: @RachelSolomon I hate doing this to people but if you could get me a screenshot of your folder directory, so I can see how your project is set up.

Comment: @BillF I can do that. Just to clarify - do you mean a screenshot of my Tomcat directory?

Comment: @RachelSolomon mainly your project. for tomcat, i just need to know where under your tomcat your war is placed if it's under your tomcat directory